# C - Linux Char Device openat() returns EINVAL

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I'm writing my first Linux LKM. It's a simple chardev that has some basic `read`, `write`, `open`, `release`  functions with a `mutex` lock. It compiles successfully, but when I try to open the chardev by `cat /dev/kbschar`, I get the following error

```
cat: /dev/kbschar: Invalid argument
```

The source code is [on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/cocoa1231/kbullshit/blob/master/main.c). I've linked to the `main.c` file. You can find the `Makefile` in the repository

The output of `dmesg` [is here](https://pastebin.com/6snKT3zB). I also used `ftrace`'s `function_graph` tracer and filtered by `:mod:main`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/MN84t8yZ) is the output of that.  Finally, I also ran `strace cat /dev/kbschar` to see where I was getting the `EINVAL` error. [Here](https://pastebin.com/xQgA8HcV) is the output to that. We have the `EINVAL` error at line 32.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of your `dev_open` function:

```
return true;
```

is not good. You're supposed to return an error code (negative errno) or zero for success. Whatever `true` is (probably defined as 1 somewhere?) it's not valid.